# CosmosDB: Efficiently migrate records from a large container

Tags: azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage

I created a container in `CosmosDB` that tracks metadata about each API call (timestamp, user id, method name, duration, etc.). The partition key is set to `UserId` and each id is a random `Guid`. This container also helps me enforce rate limiting for each user. So far so good. Now, I want to periodically clean up this container by moving records to an `Azure Table` (or something else) for long-term storage and generate reporting. Migrating records also helps me avoid the 20GB logical partition size limit.

However, I have concerns about whether cross-partition queries will bite me eventually. Say, I want to migrate all records that were created a week ago. Also, let's assume I have millions of active users. Thus, this container sees a lot of activity and I can't specify a partition key in my query. I'm reading that we should avoid cross-partition queries when RU/s and storage size are both big. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-query-container). I have no idea how many physical partitions I'm going to end up dealing with in the future.

Is my design completely off? How can I efficiently migrate records? I'm hoping that the CosmosDB team can see this and help me find a solution to this problem.

Comment: 4c74356b41's advice is good. Table storage is super-cheap for large volumes of data over time - way cheaper than CosmosDb. So my question is that if you want to eventually store API call history in Table storage, why write to CosmosDB in the first place? Is there a reason why you wouldn't write directly to Table storage and skip CosmosDb altogether?

Comment: Rob, I don't have much experience with Table storage at the moment. In Cosmos v3, I write LINQ queries with `Where` and `Count` methods to enforce rate limiting on specific API route and userId combos. Does Table storage support this type of LINQ functionality? Just like your recommendation, I'd love to use Table storage if I could. I get an `IOrderedQueryable<T>` with CosmosDB. I don't want to fetch all Table rows in memory for filtering and counting.

Comment: Ah, so you're querying CosmosDb on each API call to find out how many queries the user has performed in the throttle window? And if the query rate exceeds a threshold, you deny the API request and return something like a HTTP 429?

Comment: Exactly! The functionality was implemented a long time ago. Of course, now I need to migrate stale data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier approach would be to use a [time to live](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/time-to-live) and just write events\data to both cosmos db and table storage at the same time, so that it stays in table storage forever, but is gone from Cosmos DB when TTL expires. You can specify TTL at document level, so if you need some documents to live longer - that can be done.

Another approach might be using the [change feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed#use-cases).

Answer (score 2):

Based on your updated comments:

- You are writing a CosmosDb doc for each API request.
- When an API call is made, you are querying CosmosDB for all API calls within a given time period with the partition being the userId. If the document count exceeds the threshold, return an error such as a HTTP 429.
- You want to store API call information for longterm analysis.

If your API is getting a lot of use from a lot of users, using CosmosDB is going to be expensive to scale, both from a storage and a processing standpoint.

For rate limiting, consider [this rate limiting pattern](https://redislabs.com/redis-best-practices/basic-rate-limiting/) using Redis cache. [The StackExchange.Redis package](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/) is mature, and has lots of guidance and code samples. It'll be a much lighter weight and scalable solution to your problem.

So for each API call, you would:

1. Read the Redis key for the user making the call. Check to see if it exceeds your threshold.
2. Increment the user's Redis key.
3. Write the API invocation into to Azure Table Storage, probably with the partition key being the userId, and the rowkey being whatever makes sense for you.

Comment: I considered Redis at the time of implementing rate-limiting in CosmosDB. I even remember asking a CosmosDB team member if Redis is overkill on top of CosmosDB. The answer was yes. See this: https://medium.com/@marcodesanctis2/using-azure-cosmos-db-as-your-persistent-geo-replicated-distributed-cache-b381ad80f8a0 Ideally, I'd like to avoid complicating the back-end design with another layer / point of failure. At the same time, cost might be the biggest pain point. Thank you. I'll consider this option.

Comment: If you do go with CosmosDb for rate limiting your API, I second 4c74356b41's suggestion of using an Azure Function to monitor the CosmosDB Change Feed. For each change, you can see if it's an API call, then write the API call to Table Storage.

Comment: This is an important choice. I'm leaning towards the Redis approach considering, in my case, CosmosDB will charge 3 extra RU/s for every API call (one to read the current count, one to write the doc, and one for TTL). Is there any C# example out there for Redis rate-limiting? I couldn't find any.

Comment: I don't have any examples off of the top of my head, unfortunately.

Comment: I moved API tracking to Table Storage and implemented a Redis cache layer. All is working fine. Thank you for the direction! I chose the other answer as the accepted answer since it fits the question better, but I ultimately went with your direction.